# How to format Postgresql CREATE INDEX statement to canonical (like in pg_indexes.indexdef)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I create index by query:

```sql
CREATE INDEX test_1 ON partner (lower(name)) WHERE is_company is TRUE;
```

In indexes table index definition looks other way.

```sql
> SELECT indexef from pg_indexes where indexname = 'test_1';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| indexdef                                                                                           |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| CREATE INDEX test_1 ON public.partner USING btree (lower((name)::text)) WHERE (is_company IS TRUE) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

There are additional parenthesis, scheme name, type casting, USING statement.
How can I convert original query to that format?
I want it to understand recreate `test_1` index or not.

Comment: Whatever you see in the pg_indexes is just an expanded version of what you typed. What is your concern exactly?

Comment: Your SQL statement `CREATE INDEX...` uses the "natural" form of the index. The database converts it to the "canonical" form, and that's what you see when you are retrieving it back. There's no practical difference between both.